# Batch Processing

Tags: c, multithreading, batch-processing

I have a list of strings that I want to output to different files according to a key for each file(this key is present in the list, so if this key is 1 in certain node then the string needs to be written to file 1.txt and if the key is 2 then the output should be redirected to 2.txt and so on...).

What I was thinking, is to assign each list member a unique key which makes it a unique record, and then spawn multiple threads depending on the number of processors available in the system. The thread redirect the output of a node from a pool of nodes(that is my list) to the concerned file. I was skeptical whether this is a good design for batch processing. Or should I just have one thread to do the whole output thingy.

ps - Before I get bashed or anything let me tell you I am just a curious learner.

Comment: Is the input list of strings text file as well?  If so this sounds like it would be easier with an (awk/perl/phython/php etc) script.  As @bobah says you could quite well be IO bound, in which case multi-threading won't help you.

Comment: No its simply a linked list whose one member is a string. And I want the program to be portable across various processors, i.e. it should work on a single processor as well as multiple processor. I do have working data structure somewhere in my program that can tell me how many processors I have in the system. So should I make two different versions for uniprocessor and multiprocessor?(depending on how many processors are present in the system ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

Make it single threaded. Then run, find what your bottleneck is. If you find out, that your bottleneck is CPU and not disk IO, then enable parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your processing steps is:

- select file by the key
- write item to file

I think this is not the case when parallel processing can result in performance improvement. If you want to speed up this code - use buffering and asynchronous I/O.

- for each file maintain a flag - *write-in-progress*
- when you want to write something to file - check this flag

  - if *write-in-progress* is False:

    - set *write-in-progress* = True
    - add your item to buffer
    - start writing this buffer to file asynchronously
  - if *write-in-progress* is True:

    - add your item to buffer
- when pending asynchronous operation is completed

  - check is there is nonempty buffer, if so start async write

There is more simple approach: use buffering and synchronous I/O. It will be slower than asynchronous approach described above, but not very much. You can start several thread and traverse list in each thread independently. Each thread must process only some unique set of keys. For example, you can use two threads, first thread must write only items with odd keys, second thread must write only items with even keys.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, kind of.
This will make it clear(possibly):
I have a linked list whose node has following members:
(i)String to_write(of certain length).
(ii)file_name(the name/id of file where I append 'to_write').
and some more things.
Can I make this writing of data to file parallel, say by indexing the list? If I have multiple processors available why not make full use of it?
This is just to learn a bit about parallel processing and batch processing. But I guess you're correct with the explanation that you gave.

Comment: contd. 
As the bottleneck will be the number of files that I have so no matter how many threads I have, only 1 thread can write to one file at a time. so I guess the flag(or semaphore) for each file approach combined with buffer will be better.

Comment: You don't need to index list to process it in parallel. Just iterate through list in each thread independently and ignore some elements. If keys distributed uniformly - no load balancing will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a concurrency model for that - however serious it sounds :)

First analyze what can be done at the same time and is unrelated to each other. Imagine each step of your program is executed on different machine with a sort of communication between, e.g. IP network.

Then draw a flow between these instances (actions/machines). Mark what resources actions need to perform, e.g. a list, a file. Mark resources as separate instances (same as actions and machines).

Put the file system in your picture to see if writing separate files may be sped up or it will end in the file system and thus it will be serialized again.

Connect the instances. And see if you get any benefit. It could look like that:

```
        list
         |
      list reader
        /  \     \
       /    \     ----------\
    file    file          file
   writer  writer        writer
     |        |              |
  file 1    file 2         file 3
     \        /              |
      \      /               |
     file system 1      file system 2
```

In the example you can see that it may make sense to get some parallel execution